# Python-sqlite-how to save a database output to a text file

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have a python program which uses SQLite features. The program lists First name, last name, and type of pet. The program is saved as a DB file called pets.db. I want to be able to convert this database into text. To do this, I tried to use a dump statement in command prompt. Here is my output:

```
 sqlite> .output file location of pets.db

   Usage: .output FILE

   sqlite> .dump

   PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

COMMIT;

sqlite>.exit





However, pets.txt does not exist when I type

dir pets.txt /s /p
```

in command prompt.

Any suggestions? I used http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-dump/ as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.output` command is slightly off. Based on your comment, it sounds like you're typing `.output file $(location of pets.db)`. This isn't how the command works.

First off, open the database you want to dump with the command `sqlite3 pets.db`. This will open your databse. You can ensure you have the database you want by using the command `.tables`. If you see tables in the database, you know you've opened it correctly. If not, the command won't display anything.

Once you've opened the file, `.output $(filename).txt` will actually set the output to a specified file. Now, you can use the `.dump` command. It'll take a moment for the driver to actually write the whole db if it's somewhat large.

Once the file is finished writing, you can exit with `.exit`.

Comment: There are no transactions; this is the .dump output.

Comment: I added the .output(file location)/db_dump.txt. I then used a .dump statement. The file still does not exist. Also, the begin transactions  output appears whenever  I type .dump.

Comment: @Akshay: Wait, are you actually typing `.output FILE path.txt`? If so, you don't need to pass `FILE` as an argument. That's just a placeholder in the documentation.